# Maximum camera frame rate

Tags: camera

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi 2 with a camera (either the NoIR camera or a USB one) for [visual servoing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Servoing).

This requires a very small and consistent delay from image capture to sending out the command signal to my servo motors.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to synchronise my code with the camera's capture rate so that the delay is constant?
2. What is the maximum frame rate possible on something like the NoIR camera? (even if it means turning the resolution right down).

I am happy to accept answers of the form: "the fastest theoretical fram rate is X, but you'd have to dig into the drivers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no theoretical data here. The [new camera mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-camera-mode-released/)(s) can go 90 fps at 640x480. As for the timing, I think it's up to your code to handle the incoming data stream.

Comment: I think that's new camera *mode*.  The hardware didn't change, it was a firmware update.  Just in case anyone is worried about buying the "new" version of the camera.

Comment: @goldilocks corrected, phone auto-correct lol